# *SQL Error: Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a database have 2 table `website` and `domains`, and a website can store more than 1 domain, and I was create a `view`:

```
create view website_infor
as
select
    w.name 'Website Name',
    (
        select url
        from domains
        where company_id = w.id
    )
    'Domains URL'
from
    website w;
```

And SQL response error:

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Now I want get all domain match with website ID, someone can help me?
Thanks more and sorry for my English so bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JOIN`s suggested by the other answers will return multiple rows of data for each website (one for each domain). If you only want to get one row of data for each website, use a `GROUP_CONCAT` instead i.e.

```
create view website_infor
as
select
    w.name 'Website Name',
    (
        select GROUP_CONCAT(url)
        from domains
        where company_id = w.id
    )
    'Domains URL'
from
    website w;
```

If for example you have a website example which refers to example.net and example.com, a `JOIN` will return two rows:

```
Website Name | Domains URL
-------------|------------
example      | example.net
-------------|------------
example      | example.com
-------------+------------
```

while the `GROUP_CONCAT` will return one row:

```
Website Name | Domains URL
-------------|-------------------------
example      | example.net, example.com
-------------+-------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `JOIN` instead of `Sub-Query`:

```
SELECT
    w.name 'Website Name',
    D.url 'Domains URL'
FROM website w
JOIN domains D ON W.id = D.company_id
```

Comment: @TylerTrần, You are Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do `JOIN`s with domain table

```
SELECT 
       w.name AS 'Website Name',
       d.url AS 'Domains URL'     
FROM  website w
INNER JOIN domains d ON d.company_id = w.id
```